# MASM32 Local Variables?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, masm32

I need help understanding MASM32 LOCAL Macro. I know the LOCAL variables are push to the stack. However, I'm trying to use them to store a temporary value. Here is a quick snippet.

```
FormatError PROC USES EBX ECX
LOCAL NumComma:DWORD, NumPeriod:DWORD
```

.
.
.

```
.WHILE ecx < eax
    mov bl, [edx + ecx]
    .IF bl == ","
        inc [NumComma]
    .ELSEIF bl == "."
        inc [NumPeriod]
    .ENDIF
    inc ecx
.ENDW

mov ebx, [NumComma]
mov ecx, [NumPeriod]
```

EBX = 004059B5h
ECX = 7EFDE000h

There are not 4,217,269(004059B5h) Commas. And there are not 2,130,567,168(7EFDE000h) Periods...
They both don't seem to be addresses holding any value... Really lost on how to inc Local variables.

Side Note:
Kinda new to programming Assembly...

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Just changed the question, sorry, kinda in a rush... Assignment due in 3 hours... haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A local (stack) variable mus tbe initialized if you intend to use it. So you should do somehting like this:

```
xor eax, eax
mov NumPeriod, eax
mov NumComma, eax
```

If you are using variables from the `BSS` or `DATA` segment, they are preinitialized, but stack variables have the values whatever happens to be on the stack, when the function is called.

Comment: Found out MASM is just pure evil... When you use LOCAL macro it also set up the stack frame for you... That's nice Except when you want to set it up!!!!
evil... pure evil

Comment: However, you probably would have saved me time... Still because I did not know they had to be inited

Comment: Yes, when you use locals or params, then MASM will automatically create the stackframe with you. That's why it's always good to post a full sample of the code. If you post a snippet you may miss the important bits and we can't know whats wrong of course. Keep in mind also, that if you let masm set up the stackframe for you, you must use `ret` and not i.e. `retn` otherwise the stackeframe will not be automatically destroyed as MASM also generates the epilogue in this case.

Comment: then don't use PROC and ENDP in masm. In that case you don't loose control over your source code :).